# visual talking head agent

Tags: artificial-intelligence, chatbot

I'm creating a chat bot with an animated head at the side. So far I have completed the chat bot and I'm looking to make an animated head. I have no experience with 3d modellers so could you suggest any tools I could use for this? My bot is written in c# and uses AIML files in visual studio. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thought about using a 3rd party avatar like sitepal.com or haptek.com ?  Note that I have no stake in either of those applications.... I'm just someone who's also investigated what I could do to have an avatar as part of my chatbots as well!